# Compare Data on XML to MySQL Table

Tags: php, xml, compare

I am getting xml data via web service

```
<ITEMS>
     <item id="uilldmduw"/>
     <item id="wl2323ldsaw"/>
</ITEMS>
```

I need to compare this list to the 'items' table on my data base and return only rows that have an id that exist also in one of the xml nodes.

XML can contain few hundreds of nodes, items table contains 100k's of rows

What will be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Parse the XML (for example using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)) and collect all ids into an array. Then use that array in a database query:

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT id, field, field2
                  FROM table
                  WHERE
                    id IN(%s)',
                 implode(',', $id_array));
```

(Please note that this code assumes that all elements in the `$id_array` is either guaranteed to be integer or are correctly SQL escaped. You will need to ensure this yourself before using this code, otherwise you risk an SQL injection)

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a list of all rows which have an id present in the xml file.

```
<?php
$xml = '<ITEMS>
        <item id="uilldmduw"/>
        <item id="wl2323ldsaw"/>
    </ITEMS>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// do an xpath query and get all item id's 
$result = $xml->xpath( '//item[@id]' );

$idList = array();
foreach($result as $node) {
    $idList[] = '"' . (string)$node[ 'id' ] . '"';
}

// all id's are now in a string sequence
$idList = implode( ',', $idList );

$results = array();

// select all rows which have an id in the sequence
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (' . $idList . ')';
$run = mysql_query( $sql, $db_conn );

if($run && mysql_num_rows($run)) {
    while(($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($run))!=false) {
        $result[] = $fetch;//store the results the way you want.
    }
}

//$results now contains the desired result
?>
```

Hope this helps.